# what to use session.beginTranscation or session.getTranscation?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Spring mvc and Hibernate.
I am confused between beginTranscation and getTranscation.
Using anyone code is working But i want to know which is correct way.

Below is my code form Dao class

```
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction().begin();
        executeQuery = session.createQuery(sql);
        Employee emp = (Employee) executeQuery.uniqueResult();
        session.beginTransaction().commit();
```

can anyone tell me what to use beginTranscation or getTrancation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**session.getTransaction().begin()** - assumes that transaction already exists (you already have started transaction) , and it will use it.

**session.beginTransaction()** - will check if there is already an existing transaction, if so it will not create a new transaction, and will use the running one. If no transaction exists yet, it will create a new one.

So clearly depends on your needs.

Also, be carefull, as you are calling `sessionBeginTransaction()` twice, so change your code to

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
executeQuery = session.createQuery(sql);
Employee emp = (Employee) executeQuery.uniqueResult();
tx.commit();
```

And this `session.beginTransaction().begin()` call is equal to `session.beginTransaction()`

In general as you already have configured Spring environment, Spring has powerfull [transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) , so instead of handling transactions by yourself, stick to what offers a framework you are using. At least you can try to use programmatic way of managing transactions (e.g. [TransactionTemplate](http://simplespringtutorial.com/springProgrammaticTransactions.html))

Comment: session.beginTransaction() and session.beginTransaction().begin() both are same or is there any difference in them.?

Comment: I've updated my answer, calls are identical, so better to use shortened version, without calling begin()